# Where can I find Report from Wortham and Villager's Journal?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I (and it seems like a lot of other people) am missing two quest lore reports for an achievement: "Report from Wortham" (the first) and "Villager's Journal" (the last).

Where can I find them?

By the way, someone [here](http://d3db.com/item/i/villagers-journal#comment) says that the Villager's journal can only be found in the Lyceum, a dungeon which currently seems bugged. Is this true?

Comment: Bashiok has confirmed that the Lyceum is currently bugged ([link](http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/224794-lyceum-and-villagers-journal/#post87))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the report on a dead body named Wortham Villager Corpse, he was very well marked and appears to be a non-random encounter.  It was just prior to getting to Leoric's palace as @Alok mentioned, in the Northern Highlands.

[image: map view]
[image: not map view]

The Villager’s Journal spawns in a [Old Keepsake Box at the Old Ruins](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5889879936#7), it was previously reported in The Lyceum a random dungeon whose location is discussed in [this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/67855/10260).  It was unobtainable prior to patch 1.0.3, which led to most of the confusion around it but it is [now dropping again](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5870797732).

Comment: I just did several runs on Old Tristram road and the only lore books found there are part of the Old Tristram series of People books (Cain's Old Journal(1&2), Gillian's Journal (1&2), Lost Journal, Old Diary, and Despina's Journal) and the World Lore Traveller's Journal and Warriv's Journal. The Tristram People books can be found under a body hanging from a tree - are you sure you aren't confusing on this one?

Comment: @skovacs1 I will have to recheck now to verify or modify.

Comment: Actually, is there a chance that you're confusing the Villager's Journal with the Traveler's Journal?

Comment: @Heishe Exactly why I edited my answer to reflect ~@skovacs1's comment

Comment: Can this answer be updated to reflect the latest patch?

Comment: @fbueckert Done

Answer (score 4):

As of [1.0.3](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/6457499#bugfixes), the Villager's Journal can now be found in the keepsake box in the ruins of Old Tristram.

Also, as of 1.0.3, the Lyceum is no longer bugged.  It is found in the center of the Southern Highlands as described in the posts above.

Answer (score 1):

I found Report from Wortham in the road after the spider dungeon, on the way to Leoric's palace and before finding the staff. It was on a dead body right on the road at a point where it ascends up a little hill - but I'm unsure if this is fixed or semi-randomized location.

[image: Wortham Villager corpse]

Found in the connecting area between **Northern Highlands** and **Leoric's Hunting Grounds**.

*Update*: As noted by [Tyri](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/27860/tyri), Villager's Journal now spawns ingame, from the Old Keepsake Box in the ruins. Attaching a screenshot, but the actual location of the box can be in several alternate locations in that area.

[image: Villager's Journal]