# Where is The Lyceum?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

*The Lyceum* is listed as one of the objectives for the *No Stone Unturned* achievement, yet nobody seems to know where it is. Where is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are all the random dungeons?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66418/where-are-all-the-random-dungeons)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Lyceum is one of the random dungeons in the Southern Highlands. It has a fixed spawn point but shares it with several other random spawns. The entrance area looks like this:

[image]

Its spawning place is slightly northeast of the entrance to the Southern Highlands:

[image]

This spawn point is shared with The Revenge of Gharbad, the Empty Servants House, Ancient Pyre or the event pictured below, among others (you can see the similarity of the place, also it seems like it's the only place which can host such a large environment):

[image]

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Does it have a fixed spawn location as some of the dungeons do (Watch Tower comes to mind) or is its location also randomized? If it has a fixed spawn location, could you describe it? Are there any restrictions on finding this location (like only on X difficulty or during Quest X or maybe something else)? If your information is from the beta, you should note this in your answer as the information may have changed in the released version.

Comment: I'll edit in what I know. By the way, this is not from beta (the Southern Highlands weren't available in the beta).

Comment: Thanks. That would be excellent. I did not have access to the beta so I had no idea, but as I've seen some answers reference the beta, I just wanted to be thorough. I and many others have yet to find this dungeon despite hours of attempts so any information to speed up searching and improve your answer is appreciated.

Comment: Your description was a bit unclear. Perhaps it is unclear to you how things are placed on the map. ***Whether* a random dungeon/event appears at all is clearly random and *you don't need to explain that*. *Where* a dungeon/event locale appears is selected from a limited pool of locations for that dungeon/event locale.** ie. *If* Watch Tower appears, it will *always* appear on the left edge of Northern Highlands. If you are unsure of the pool of locations available to Lyceum, you needed only to say that. I revised your description to improve clarity.

Comment: Updated the post :)

Comment: As of the release version, it's not certain that the lyceum is in Southern Highlands. The image is taken from here: http://www.diablowiki.net/File:SHLyceum2.jpg and this images dates back from the 8th of November 2011. Its location may have changed since.

Comment: I think it should still be there, and if not, at least in the Northern highlands, though. The lighting and general surroundings (especially the enemies) fit well. Also it's unlikely that Blizzard would simply change the location of this dungeon for no apparent reason.

Comment: Heishe, sorry to contradict you, but to the dozens of people searching on Normal and Nightmare, and the several on Hell, nobody has confirmed this location. We think it may be bugged at the moment (along with Villager's journal), and I have sent in a support ticket about both to see if this is as-intended, etc. Everyone who has heard of someone "finding it" has been hear-say.

Comment: well, you're not contradicting me. that's exactly what i said.

Comment: [Bashiok confirmed this bug](http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/224794-lyceum-and-villagers-journal/#post87)

Comment: As of the <a href="http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/6457499#bugfixes">patch today</a>, the Lyceum is no longer bugged. It is found in the center of the Southern Highlands as described in the posts above.

Comment: I've just been in The Lyceum. Forgot to make a screenshot, but it is exactly at the place mentioned in this post. :)

Comment: does this dungeon spawn on any difficulty levels?